# GetAllCategories request => Unknown column 'c1_0.id' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm still a newbie ... I created a "Category" entity and wanted that my categories may accept children categories ... I can create a category and specify if it accepts another categoryId as a parent (it's well functionning I mean). Now I want to get the whole list of my categories but I get the following error message :

```
Unknown column 'c1_0.id' in 'field list' ...
```

Here is my Entity :

```
@Table(name="category", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "title")
})
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") // We use @OneToOne annotation to refer a category to its parent
    private Category parentId;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>(); // We use 

    @OneToMany to refer a category to its children
    @Column(name="created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private Date updateAt;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categoriesList")
    private Set<Pdf> pdfList = new HashSet<>();

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String title, Category parentId, List<Category> children, Date createdAt, Date updateAt, Set<Pdf> pdfList) {
        this.title = title;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.children = children;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
        this.pdfList = pdfList;
    }
```

GetCategoriesList in my controller :

```
    @GetMapping("")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN'), hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<CategoryDTO>> getCategoriesList() throws EmptyListException {
        // Le flux de datas retourné par getAllAlerts() est traité pour que chaque data soit convertie en class AlertDTO et retournée sous forme de List
        List<CategoryDTO> categoryDTOList = service.getAllCategories().stream().map(category -> modelMapper.map(category, CategoryDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(categoryDTOList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Dtos
From client to server :

```
@Data
public class CategoryDTOWayIN {
    String title;
    Category parentId;
    Date createdAt;
    Date updateAt;
}
```

From server to client :

```
@Data
public class CategoryDTO {
    Integer id;
    String title;
    Category parentId;
    Date createdAt;
    Date updateAt;
}
```

[Datas in mySql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrRHM.png)

I tried many tricks to get the correct results but nothing succeed ... Hope you'll be able to give me a clue ! Thanks in advance to the community.

Comment: put all your information as formatted text in the question itself. please don't ask us to visit x external links

Comment: The column name in the database is `category_id` but in the entity class you have defined it as `id`.

Comment: Ho my God ... Thanks ... the mistake was too big to see it correctly !!! Thanks for your Tiger eye Mar-z ...